# Xargs: Alias substitution fails despite expanding the alias

Tags: bash, alias, xargs

I have the following command:

`fd --type f -0 --full-path $HOME/something/something_inside_something | fzf --read0 --print0 --exit-0 --preview 'bat {1}' | xargs -r -0 vim`

Where vim is an alias of:

`NVIM_APPNAME=mynvim nvim`

The command fails at the alias. I know it is correct apart from the alias, because when run without it (e.g `xargs -r -0 nvim` where nvim is not an alias,) it works fine.

I have tried both `alias xargs='xargs '` and `xargs -r -0 bash -ic vim`

I have also tried a multitude of other proposed workarounds I have found on the topic in similar questions here and on the internet at large.

Anyone got any tips?

Ps: Apropos of nothing, anyone have any idea why `--preview 'bat {1}'` will fail to display (some) files it would normally display without a hitch?

Comment: `Anyone got any tips?` Is a too broad question. I do not understand what is the problem. How is alias related to the command? What is the problem? `Alias substitution fails despite expanding the alias` What fails where and with what message?

Comment: @KamilCuk at the second line I say "where vim is an alias of" and at the third line you see the alias. The rest is self explanatory.

Comment: xargs isn't _supposed_ to be able to start aliases. It uses the `execve()` syscall -- that directly tells the kernel to start another program with no shell involved. Aliases are a shell feature. Connect the dots.

Comment: (and alias expansion is entirely turned off in scripts by default; in general, it's better practice to avoid them altogether and stick to functions)

Comment: Phillipe's answer works because of the `-i` -- interactive mode turns on aliases that are defined in `.bashrc`. That's lousy practice, though; `.bashrc` is written by human users for human users; those human users usually aren't thinking about "how will this change script behavior?" when they update their dotfiles, so if you want to write robust and reliable code you really _should_ be thinking about what's supposed to work, not just what does happen work for you in the one environment you're testing against right now.

Comment: @Duffy if you would read my original post, you would notice I list -i as one of the things I did (and expected to work.) The reason Phillipe's answer works, is not because of the -i , but because of the "$1". That's what I had forgotten to include. Sometimes the mind falters, that's my only excuse. Also, I don't use xargs that often. Regarding robust and leliable code. Not once did I mention I am testing something, nor that this is for a system in multi-user environment. This *my* bashrc, in *my* machine. Not everything has to be deployed on a server.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Vikare is right in saying my answer is not about `-i`, but about the usage of `-c`. It would apply even if `vim` is a function instead of an alias.

Comment: @Philippe `ls` command is *usually* an alias `EVERYWHERE` like `alias ls='ls --color=auto'`  . You can run a quck check with and without `-i` as below: `echo 1 2 3 4 5 |xargs -rn1 bash -c 'ls /'` vs `echo 1 2 3 4 5 |xargs -rn1 bash -ic 'ls /'` and see which colorizes the output (aliases active vs non-active). Duffy is correct about the `-i`

Comment: @Vikare You are missing the point Duffy is making: From bash man page: `Aliases allow a string to be substituted for a word when it is used as the first word of a simple command.` Notice **`FIRST WORD`** and **`SIMPLE COMMAND`**.  Firsrt step should always be `man bash` or `online man bash` at https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash instead of stupid non-questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
xargs -r -0 bash -ic 'vim "$1"' _
```

Comment: The first parameter that `xargs` will pass to bash will show up in `$0`, not `$1`. Quickly testable via `echo 1 2 3 4 5 6| xargs -rn2 bash -ic 'echo $1'` (2 args per subprocess to show you that `xargs` is working instead of confusing you further if used with `xargs -rn1`), so the extra `_` isn't required if you use `$0` directly

Comment: @Samveen Indeed we can use `$0`. Don't you think it's more `natural` to use `$1` ?

Comment: @Phillippe **No**. As to why:  From `man bash` :  `If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string.  If there are arguments after the command_string, the  first  argument  is  assigned to $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters.`

Comment: @Samveen What I meant is that in a normal script, you wouldn't use `$0` to mean `first argument`.

Comment: As per standard doctrine, manpage documentation is the canonical source of truth on behaviour. Anyone who reads the man page will wonder as to why the `_` is used, becuase `-c` and `$0` *is **normal** behaviour*. So please add a note about the `_` to your answer. Also, the question poster hasn't bothered to read the man page. If he had, the question would be moot. Please don't encourage his behaviour.

Comment: No one said manpage documentation is NOT the canonical source of truth. We were discussing about `$0` or `$1`. Do you still think `$0` is the way to go ?

Comment: Yes. `$0` over `$1` + `_`  every day: The source of information is widely available, and as a consequence I've used `xargs -rn1 bash -c '$0' ` for the last 20 years.

Comment: I guess if you have `-rn5`, you'd do something like `xargs -rn5 bash -c 'echo "$0" "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4"', right ?`

Comment: @Samveen How does it compare with `xargs -rn5 bash -c 'echo "$@"' _` ?

Comment: I live and learn about new use cases every day (+1). Personally, I have never had to go beyond `-rn2`.